# jQuery scroll loader doubling result when scrolled quickly

Tags: jquery

I have made a jQuery script that loads items from the database when the user scrolls. Only problem is that when a user scrolls very quickly after page load the result of the script doubles up so the information from the database is shown twice. Not really sure what's going on here but the script is below. It's all on doc ready by the way.

```
function last_item_funtion() 
     { 
     var ID=$(".newsItem:last").attr("id");
     $('#feedLoader').html('<img src="../files/images/bigLoader.gif" style="display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">');
     $.post("AJAX/scroll_feed.php?action=get&last_item_id="+ID,

     function(data){
     if (data != "") {
     $(".newsItem:last").after(data); 
     }
     $('#feedLoader').empty();
     });
     }; 

     $(window).scroll(function(){
     if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
     last_item_funtion();
     }
     });
```

This isn't my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2LdvT/1/) but it shows in a nutshell what the script does. It doesn't show the problem I am having but i cannot replicate that as I can't put a whole database on jsfiddle.

**UPDATE**
After having a play I have realized that it's not when the user scrolls straight after page load it's when the user does one continuous scroll instead of a short one. From this I am guessing that jQuery does not register the data has been loaded until the scroll is stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess the `scroll` event is fired multiple times, so the request is done multiple times. Try the following:

```
function bind_scroll() {
    $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            $(window).unbind('scroll');
            last_item_funtion();
        }
    });
}

function last_item_funtion() {
    var ID = $(".newsItem:last").attr("id");
    $('#feedLoader').html('<img src="../files/images/bigLoader.gif" style="display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">');
    $.post("AJAX/scroll_feed.php?action=get&last_item_id=" + ID,

    function (data) {
        if (data != "") {
            $(".newsItem:last").after(data);
        }
        $('#feedLoader').empty();
        bind_scroll();
    });
};

bind_scroll();
```

It binds the `scroll` event, and unbinds it after it is triggered. The event is bound again after the request is finished.

(You might also check out [jQuery.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/), but I have never used it.)

**EDIT:**
After doing some testing, the scroll event gets triggered a lot even though we unbind it, so here is an updated example that uses a global variable to tell the `scroll`-callback if it's loading something already, or if it's ok to do a new post request:

```
window.scroll_loading = false;

function last_item_funtion() {
    var ID = $(".newsItem:last").attr("id");
    $('#feedLoader').html('<img src="../files/images/bigLoader.gif" style="display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">');

    $.post("AJAX/scroll_feed.php?action=get&last_item_id=" + ID,
        function (data) {
            window.scroll_loading = false;
            if (data != "") {
                $(".newsItem:last").after(data);
            }
            $('#feedLoader').empty();
        }
    );
};

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if (window.scroll_loading == true) {
        return;
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
        window.scroll_loading = true;
        console.log("FIRE!");
        last_item_funtion();
    }
});
```

Comment: This works but only once. If the user scrolls down again it does not work.

Comment: It was an error in the code, it unbinded the event every scroll event, and not for when it is at the bottom at the screen, so I moved the `$(window).unbind('scroll');` inside the `if`. But did some testing myself, and it still did some weird things, so I created another example that should work.

Answer (score 0):

haven't tested this but see if this solves your problem

```
$(window).die("scroll").live("scroll",function(){
     if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
     last_item_funtion();
     }
     });
```